# Variable assignment function in Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

So my teacher for formal methods of logicgave this definition for variant sequences and I just cannot follow what this is asking me. When he explained the concept it made since but then he gave us an example on the board that said

> Consider the language $$L = \{R\}$$ with a single relational predicate $R$
> and model $$M = \langle D, I \rangle$$ for $L$ with domain $$D = \{a, a', b, b'\}$$ such that
> $$I(R) = \{\langle a, a \rangle, \langle a, a' \rangle, \langle a', a' \rangle, \langle b, b \rangle, \langle b, b' \rangle, \langle b', b' \rangle\}$$.
> Let $s: Var → D$ be such that $$s(x) = a\text{ for all }x ∈ Var.$$ $[\![Rv_0v_1]\!]^{s_{[v_1\mapsto d]}}$

and I just couldn't figure it out. Is x now v1 in the example? and where does v0 go to??? Sorry for the terrible notation I tried to use MathJax but was struggling to get it to work the way I wanted it to.
[definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qon94.png)

Comment: Please, format formulas accordingly...

Comment: A variable assignment function $s$ is a function that maps variables of the language: $v_0,v_1, \ldots$ into objects of the domain $D$, i.e. $s(v_i)=d_i \in D$.

Comment: In your example you have $D = \{ a, a', b, b' \}$ and $s$ is defined such that $s(v_i)=a$ for every variable $v_i$, i.e. for every element of the set $\text {Var}$ of the variables of the language. That's all.

Comment: In conclusion: "where does $v_0$ go to?" $s(v_0)=a$.

Answer (score 1):

> Is x now v1 in the example?

$x$ is a placeholder for any variable. $x$ stands for $v_1$ and also $v_0$.

> where does v0 go to?

Where $s_{[v_1 \mapsto d]}$ sends it to. In the given model, $s$ sends all variables to $a$, so $s(v_0) = a$. And applying the definition of a variant sequence, $s_{[v_0 \mapsto d]} =$ the same as $s(v_0)$ if $v_0$ is a different variable than $v_1$, and $s_{[v_0 \mapsto d]} = d$ if $v_0$ is the variable in question $v_1$. So which is it?

(BTW, you must have a typo in your post, as there is no $d$ in $D$.)